# Firebase: Why does `onAuthStateChanged` always return a user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've deleted all my cookies, nothing in localstorage or in IndexDB.

Yet, `onAuthStateChanged` always yields a user.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

The Docs explain how it adds an observable. But it does not explain what side effects it causes.

Does it add a session-ids in cookies?

How does this continuously produce a user with nothing persisted on the client??

```
firebaseClient.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {

   ... the user is ALWAYS here.
```

I wish Firebase docs would be more specific about what is going on under the hood.
So frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth utilizes in-memory, LocalStorage, SessionStorage and IndexDB internally depending on the platform, availability and authentication state persistence settings. Removing the data from the storage will result in subsequent `onAuthStateChanged()` to return `null`.

Are you refreshing your app after removing cookies, local storage / indexDB? Are you sure you have deleted everything in indexDB?

Here's a snippet of firebase authenticate user initialization:

```js
fireauth.storage.UserManager.prototype.initialize_ = function() {
  var self = this;
  // Local key.
  var localKey = fireauth.storage.UserManager.getAuthUserKey_(
      fireauth.authStorage.Persistence.LOCAL);
  // Session key.
  var sessionKey = fireauth.storage.UserManager.getAuthUserKey_(
      fireauth.authStorage.Persistence.SESSION);
  // In memory key. This is unlikely to contain anything on load.
  var inMemoryKey = fireauth.storage.UserManager.getAuthUserKey_(
      fireauth.authStorage.Persistence.NONE);
  // Migrate any old currentUser from localStorage to indexedDB.
  // This keeps any user signed in without the need for reauthentication and
  // minimizes risks of dangling Auth states.
  return this.manager_.migrateFromLocalStorage(
      localKey, this.appId_).then(function() {
    // Check if state is stored in session storage.
    return self.manager_.get(sessionKey, self.appId_);
  }).then(function(response) {
    if (response) {
      // Session storage is being used.
      return sessionKey;
    } else {
      // Session storage is empty. Check in memory storage.
      return self.manager_.get(inMemoryKey, self.appId_)
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
              // In memory storage being used.
              return inMemoryKey;
            } else {
              // Check local storage.
              return self.manager_.get(localKey, self.appId_)
                  .then(function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                      // Local storage being used.
                      return localKey;
                    } else {
                      // Nothing found in any supported storage.
                      // Check current user persistence in storage.
                      return self.manager_.get(
                          fireauth.storage.UserManager.PERSISTENCE_KEY_,
                          self.appId_).then(function(persistence) {
                            if (persistence) {
                              // Sign in with redirect operation, apply this
                              // persistence to any current user.
                              return fireauth.storage.UserManager
                                  .getAuthUserKey_(persistence);
                            } else {
                              // No persistence found, use the default.
                              return localKey;
                            }
                          });
                    }
                  });
            }
          });
    }
  }).then(function(currentKey) {
    // Set current key according to the persistence detected.
    self.currentAuthUserKey_ = currentKey;
    // Make sure only one state available. Clean up everything else.
    return self.removeAllExcept_(currentKey.persistent);
  }).thenCatch(function(error) {
    // If an error occurs in the process and no current key detected, set to
    // persistence value to default.
    if (!self.currentAuthUserKey_) {
      self.currentAuthUserKey_ = localKey;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Everything is empty. No Sessions, no localstorage, no cookie. Yet the user is being produced.

Comment: You'd have to make sure you deleted the indexDB by going devtools > application > indexDB > delete database. Also if you are not refreshing the page (reinitialize firebase auth), it could be that your auth state is persisted in-memory.